# Python unit test is not running

Tags: python, function, unit-testing

I am trying to define a test method. Currently I am not receiving any errors, but the test is not actually running. The test is trying to make sure that only the first word in a string that is in list_first_words is being returned.

```
import unittest

class TestSong(unittest.TestCase):
    def first_words_list(self):
        self.assertEqual(Song().firstwords(["hello world"]),["hello"])

if __name__ == "__main__":
    unittest.main()
```

Code that is being tested:

```
def firstwords(self,large_song_list):
        all_first_words = [] # Create an empty list
        for track in large_song_list:
            first_word = track.trackName.partition(' ')[0]
            all_first_words.append(first_word)
        return all_first_words
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to rename the test method to  `test_first_words_list`.

Tests are discovered by *unittest* only when they start with the word `test`.  See ["Organizing Test Code"](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html#organizing-test-code) in the documentation for more details.

Answer (score 2):

As described in the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html):

> A testcase is created by subclassing `unittest.TestCase`. The three individual tests are defined with methods whose names **start with the letters `test`**. This naming convention informs the test runner about which methods represent tests.

So, you need to rename the method starts with `test`.